# Min, Max, Mean Duration Time csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, time

I'm trying to subtract two columns in a CSV to create a 3rd column "Duration"
**End-Time** - **Start_time**

Each row corresponds to a User Id as well.

I can create a csv file with just the Duration column but i rather redirect it back to the original csv.

The format of these times for e.g is like **2016-11-12 01:25:24+00** - **2016-11-12 01:25:20+00**

So far I have done this

```
start_stop_sessions = pd.read_csv("start_stop_sessions.csv", parse_dates
['time_x', 'time_y'])

start_stop_sessions['time_delta'] = start_stop_sessions.time_y.values -
start_stop_sessions.time_x.values

Duration = (start_stop_sessions.time_delta)
print (Duration)
sys.stdout = open('Duration.csv', 'w')

Durationlist = ("Duration.csv") 
max_value = max(Durationlist)
min_value = min(Durationlist)
```

Am I doing this right?

**TEST DATA**

```
time_x, anonymous_id, time_y

2016-11-20 18:35:57+00, 1, 2016-11-20 19:03:31+00

2016-11-21 19:33:06+, 2, 2016-11-21 19:45:47+00

2016-11-21 19:22:52+00, 3, 2016-11-21 19:26:02+00
```

1) I would need to create a 4th column Duration

2) List of MIN, MAX, AVG for this duration column

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146571/read-and-write-on-same-csv-file)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for write file to `csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("start_stop_sessions.csv", parse_dates=['time_x','time_y'])

df['Duration'] = df['time_y'] - df['time_x']
#same as
#df['Duration'] = df['time_y'].sub(df['time_x'])
print (df)
               time_x  anonymous_id              time_y  Duration
0 2016-11-20 18:35:57             1 2016-11-20 19:03:31  00:27:34
1 2016-11-21 19:33:06             2 2016-11-21 19:45:47  00:12:41
2 2016-11-21 19:22:52             3 2016-11-21 19:26:02  00:03:10

df.to_csv('start_stop_sessions.csv', index=False)
```

Then get [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html), [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) and [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) of column `Duration` - output is [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
print (df['Duration'].min())
0 days 00:03:10

print (df['Duration'].max())
0 days 00:27:34

print (df['Duration'].mean())
0 days 00:14:28.333333
```

---

Also if need convert `timedelta` to seconds need [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Duration'] = (df['time_y'] - df['time_x']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
               time_x  anonymous_id              time_y  Duration
0 2016-11-20 18:35:57             1 2016-11-20 19:03:31    1654.0
1 2016-11-21 19:33:06             2 2016-11-21 19:45:47     761.0
2 2016-11-21 19:22:52             3 2016-11-21 19:26:02     190.0

df.to_csv('start_stop_sessions.csv', index=False)

print (df['Duration'].min())
190.0
print (df['Duration'].max())
1654.0
print (df['Duration'].mean())
868.3333333333334
```

Comment: The output I get for subtracting the first row is like 890000000000, what about using time_delta?

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: I think there is problem. Last version is 0.19.2. Is possible upgrade?

Comment: It works but is there a way to cap off the end after seconds                           0 days 00:14:50.000000000

Comment: I add solution if need output in seconds.

Comment: How do I remove the trailing 000's after seconds?   00:14:50.000000000

Comment: You can try rounding - `df['Duration'] = ((df['time_y'] - df['time_x'])).dt.round('S')`, but untested, because i have no trailing `0`

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't change anything, would datetime.timedelta work?

Comment: It seems there are some `nanoseconds`, what return `df['Duration'] = ((df['time_y'] - df['time_x'])).astype(str)` ? All values have trailing `0` ?

Comment: And then you can split by `.` and remove trailing `0` - `df['Duration'] = ((df['time_y'] - df['time_x'])).astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]` - output is not timedelta, but string.

Comment: That solves the trailing 00's but then affects the max, mean and avg. Since it expects a numeric

Comment: You are right, is necessary convert to timedelta - I hope no trailing `0` - `df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(((df['time_y'] - df['time_x'])).astype(str).str.split('.').str[0])`