# Scrape URL provided by CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV containing some columns with data, the 15th column reports a list of URLs.  Now, I need to select each URL from the column, scrape a new price from the target webpage, and then store that in the price column to update the old price.

Without the same column enumeration, here is an approximate CSV:

```
asin,title,product URL,price
KSKFUSH01,Product Title,http://....,56.00
```

Below is the sample code I wrote, but it merely prints URLs :(

```
import csv

with open('some.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for line in csv_reader:
    print(line[15])
```

Any help or suggestions about accomplishing this goal?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a sample URL?
I would recommend looking into BeautifulSoup

Comment: Hello tutorial looks great, this is sample URL: https://www.amazon.it/dp/B006H9B6XI, but basically i don't know how read each URL from csv file

Comment: If the csv has properly named columns, you can split each line by commas to extract the URLs.

Comment: i get an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Your writing is difficult to parse.  Your sample csv does not match your description.  I am updating my answer.

Comment: yes i know, piece of code i posting is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a csv writer.  You can access the URL in each line.  Here is how you can write the new price.

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('some.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

with open('newPricedata.csv', 'w', newline='') as Newcsvfile:
Pricewriter = csv.writer(Newcsvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for line in csv_reader:
page = urllib2.urlopen(line[15])
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, ‘html.parser’)
price = soup.find(‘td’, attrs={‘class’: ‘a-size-mini a-color-price ebooks-price-savings a-text-normal'})
Pricewriter.writerow(line[0]+','+,line[1]+','....+price.text)
```

Comment: seems i can't split strings

Comment: I updated my answer with some basic code that should help you.

Comment: It is bad form to do so.

Read this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146571/read-and-write-on-same-csv-file

Comment: Ok thank you! I have to test you code now, looks very professional!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good guide on how to scrape websites using BeautifulSoup
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe